# regular expressions '/[^C]/'

Tags: regex

what does this regular expressions means:

```
$rgx='/[^C]/';
```

usually this signs means not the character C
but it returns that all strings match no matter if there is a C character or not

here are the strings I checked for a match:

```
$vec=array('nI like Java%4%','I love PHP','I enjoy C#','I enjoy being paid in $');
```

Comment: That is correct. The only strings it will not match are values like `C`, `CCCC` or `CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC`.

Comment: does somebody knows the regular expression to all charcters except the one that have C# in it.

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for that. You can just use substring matching. Or you can use `/(C#)/` and negate the result (i.e. if the regex matches, it _does_ have C# in it).

Answer (score 3):

The regex matches for all strings that contain at least one character that is not a `C`. That means, it will match these strings

```
"CCCCCa"
"CC C"
"c"
```

but it will not match any of these strings:

```
"C"
"CCCCCC"
```

To ensure that the entire string doesn't contain any `C`, use `^[^C]*$`. It will ensure that you match the whole string from start to end with the `^` and `$` anchors (beware of the behaviour of multi-line strings in some languages, in Ruby you might want to use `\A[^C]*\z` instead). Inside the string, it will ensure that all the characters are matched by the `[^C]` character class (i.e are not a `C`).

Comment: And how to exclude all strings that contains at least a "C" character?

Answer (score 2):

`[^C]` matches "any character that is not a `C`", so it matches `#` in `"C#"`, for example.

If you want the regex only to match if there is no `C` *at all* in the string, use

```
^[^C]*$
```

The [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) make sure that the entire string is matched, and `[^C]*` only allows (any number of) non-`C` characters to match.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `[^C]` indicates `any character except: 'C'`

[image]

The regex `[^C]*` indicates

```
any character except: 'C' (0 or more times(matching the most amount possible))
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious: what did you use to make those diagrams?